# ng-repeat and custom directive issue in thead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to move our thead generation to a directive, but when using this, the headers lose their styling and end up bunching up on the left. Can anyone offer some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong?

The headers appear like this:

Col1Col2Col3Col4Col5

Instead of this when I use the same html without a directive. Note that these are properly aligned above their data columns:

Col1     Col2    Col3     Col4     Col5

index.html

```
<table class="table table-hover">                        
    <thead>
        <table-headers></table-headers>
    </thead> 
    ...
    ...
</table>
```

directives.js

```
app.directive('tableHeaders', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    priority: 1001,
    templateUrl: '/PATH/TO/PARTIAL/table-headers.html'
  };
});
```

table-headers.html

```
<tr>
    <th ng-cloak="true" ng-repeat="header in coreHeaders" ng-click="setOrderBy(header)"> {{header}} <i class="fa" ng-show="header == ordering.currentHeader" ng-class="ordering.reverse ? 'fa-caret-up' : 'fa-caret-down'"></i></th>
    <th class="align-right" ng-cloak="true" ng-repeat="header in statHeaders" ng-click="setOrderBy(header)">{{header}} <i class="fa" ng-show="header == ordering.currentHeader" ng-class="ordering.reverse ? 'fa-caret-up' : 'fa-caret-down'"></i></th>
</tr>
```

Comment: simple plunker , fiddle or code demo ?

Comment: You don't need to use `ng-cloak="true"` many times on a page..

Comment: It _may_ have something to do with you adding a custom element (`table-headers`) inside `thead` where the only expected elements are `tr`. I know that you're replacing them in the directive, but still it might be the issue. Try implementing `table-headers` as an attribute (`restrict: 'A'`, and remove the `replace: true` option) instead.

Comment: Tomek you are a genius! If you post as an answer will accept it.

@Vineet Can you elaborate a little more? I thought ng-cloak was used on each element you wanted to hide before it was loaded?

Comment: Not for the each element. You should use it where you're declaring your `ng-app`, that would be `<body ng-app ng-cloak>`

Comment: @Vineet This makes much more sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The only element you can have as a `<thead>`'s child is `<tr>`.** Even if you have an Angular's directive which replaces it's original markup with proper `tr` elements, the browser will be faster ;) and will mangle your html before directive compilation so the results may be quite unexpected.

Try implementing table-headers as an attribute (restrict: 'A', and remove the `replace: true` option) instead. This way it will be a valid DOM tree from the start.